# Vue.js Dialog too big for mobile device

Tags: ios, android-layout, user-interface, vuejs2

Edit: SOLVED. Leaving original for visibility, explanation at end.

I have a website with a working vue dialog with stepper that appears as intended within chrome/firefox/edge on PC, but on mobile devices there is too much text within the dialog. Attempting to scroll within the dialog scrolls the page behind the dialog, but not the dialog window itself--rendering the dialog unusable for mobile.

I have looked and have not been able to find information about optimizing vue dialogs for mobile devices. Any resources you have related to this would be helpful.

EDIT:
The dialog is created with:

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="400px" scrollable>
```

Even though I have the `scrollable` option set, the dialog does not scroll.

EDIT 2:
It turns out that default value on `scrollable` is false, meaning that if that is set, the dialog window is **NOT** scrollable. I removed this prop and am getting the behavior I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for the information through documentation, but couldn't quite find it. I was tinkering to get some different response and removed the `scrollable` prop from the dialog and fixed the issue. I found later that this prop default value is false -- meaning it will not scroll unless set to true (or omitted). [For reference](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs)